# Adding extra data into Clearance cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I'm using Clearance for authentication in a Rails 5 app, and I'm wondering what the best way to store important (to the app) user data? Right now I'm storing it in the session by overriding `Clearance::SessionsController`, but I'm worried about a user coming back to the app and the session being built from the `remember_token`.

Should I just add it into a cookie for persistence across sessions? Or is there a way to store it in Clearance's cookie? Better yet, is there a way to have Clearance add the necessary data into the session when building it from the `remember_token`?

Comment: Basically, my question boils down to if this is a proper use of a SignInGuard.

Comment: It's not clear what type of important information you are talking about. Is there a reason you need to get this from the session rather than accessing it from `current_user` which clearance gives you as a helper in controllers and views?

Comment: I'm storing the ids of records associated with an associated record, and I'd rather not be calling `current_user.associated_record.another_record` in views. So I'm keeping the ids in the session so I can set instance variables for the records. I'm trying to avoid chaining tons of methods onto the `current_user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking through the `Clearance::SessionsController`, I noticed the `redirect_signed_in_users` method being used as a `before_action`/`before_filter`. I ended up overriding that method to add in the ids I needed, similar to the `#create` method. I feel somewhat embarrassed for not noticing that sooner, because it is exactly what I needed.